# How to find the average of zero's in a particular column

Tags: sql, sql-server, gaps-and-islands

I have a situation where I have records like below.

```
+-----------+---------+---+--------+
|     a     |    b    | c |   d    |
+-----------+---------+---+--------+
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201701 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201702 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201703 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201704 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201705 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 2 | 201706 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201707 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 4 | 201708 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201709 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201710 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201711 |
| 537196605 | HZA-LOC | 0 | 201712 |
+-----------+---------+---+--------+
```

Now i want to calculate the average of zeros in here.

What i mean by this is I need the calculation to be count (zeros)/ total pair of zeros i.e 10/3 = 3.33

All the zeros that are together are considered as one value. First 5 values will be counted as 1, 7th values as 1 and 9-12 as 1 making total as 3.
Please note the value of column C is generated on the basis of grouping of A and B.
The desired result should be something like below:-

a   b   h
537196605   HZA-LOC 3.33

Please help me provide a generic solution to this as I have millions of records like this.

Comment: Data is SQL is un-ordered.  A row has now deterministic position.  In this data is ordering by `d` sufficient to put the rows in the order that you want?

Comment: Why is position 7 considered as a pair?  It is a single zero.

Comment: It would be better to call it a sequence, and not a pair. A pair is always 2.

Comment: Please add the desired result to your question (use [Edit]).

Comment: Please consider changing the title of your question. The average of some zeros is alway zero.

Comment: Given the ordering of column C does not change. Then the number of "pairs" is the number of non-zero elements of C if the last element is non-zero and the number of non-zero elements + 1 otherwise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a `ROW_NUMBER()` trick you can use to create `group_id` values.

Once you have the groups identified, count up the number of members of each group, and the number of groups, and you're done.

http://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=e10b07b6fd9f8bc7549a3b98aaff3af6

```
WITH
  enumerated_example AS
(
  SELECT
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b    ORDER BY d)   AS row_id,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, c ORDER BY d)   AS zero_row_id,
    *
  FROM
    example
),
  zero_groups AS
(
  SELECT
    row_id - zero_row_id   AS group_id,
    COUNT(*)               AS group_size
  FROM
    enumerated_example
  WHERE
    c = 0
  GROUP BY
    row_id - zero_row_id
)
SELECT
  CAST(SUM(group_size) AS DECIMAL(13, 8)) / COUNT(*)
FROM
  zero_groups
```

Comment: Thanks for the query.
The above query is returning us the result as 4.90 whereas it should be 3.33 as we have total of 10 rows with values as zero and 3 combinations of zero values. So the calculation should be 10/3 =3.33

Comment: @Himsy - Click on the link to the demo, it's giving `3.33333333`.  Are you sure you copied it correctly, or are using the same sample data?

Answer (score 1):

Here is one way using window functions

```
SELECT [Avg] = (Count(*) * 1.0) / Sum(CASE WHEN prev_c = c THEN 0 ELSE 1 END) 
FROM   (SELECT *,
               prev_c = Lag(c)OVER(ORDER BY d)
        FROM   yourtable) a
WHERE  c = 0
```

Comment: Much more succinct than my gap-and-islands group_id method :)

Comment: Out of interest, why not just have `COUNT(*)` in the outer query, in place of `MAX(tot)`?

Comment: @MatBailie - Not sure why I did that.. This makes the query more elegant

Answer (score 0):

A different (but similar) solution:

```
CREATE TABLE #Sample (a int,
                      b varchar(7),
                      c tinyint,
                      d int)

INSERT INTO #Sample
VALUES
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201701),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201702),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201703),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201704),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201705),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',2,201706),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201707),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',4,201708),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201709),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201710),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201711),
    (537196605,'HZA-LOC',0,201712);
GO

WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT *,
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b ORDER BY d) -
           ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY a, b, CASE c WHEN 0 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END ORDER BY d) AS Grp
    FROM #Sample)
SELECT a, b,
       CONVERT(decimal(6,2),COUNT(*)) / COUNT(DISTINCT Grp) AS h
FROM Groups
WHERE c = 0
GROUP BY a,b;

GO


DROP TABLE #Sample;
GO
```

Comment: Thanks for the query.
The above query is returning us the result as 4.90 whereas it should be 3.33 as we have total of 10 rows with values as zero and 3 combinations of zero values. So the calculation should be 10/3 =3.33

Comment: @Himsey, no, it returns 3.33333333333. If you are getting a different result set, then you aren't running the query correctly (have noticed a missing comma, which I've editted in).

Comment: @Larnu - He said the exact same thing to me.  I'm pretty confident he's tested it on different data.

Comment: So he did, @MatBailie. I suspect you're right. Especially odd, considering both of us provided Sample data with our solutiuons for it to run on.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is setting groups using a running sum. Then counting the number of groups per a,b combination. Thereafter, you just need to `group by`.

```
select a,b,1.0*grp_count/count(distinct grp) as result
from (select a,b,c,d,
      sum(case when c<>0 then 1 else 0 end) over(partition by a,b order by d) as grp,
      count(case when c=0 then 1 end) over(partition by a,b) as grp_count
      from tbl
     ) t
group by a,b,grp_count
```

Comment: Thanks. Your query works fine for this case. But for the below scenario

a b c d grp grp_count
960210033 NDC-KTN 262 201701 1 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 99 201702 2 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 69 201703 3 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 33 201704 4 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 11 201705 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201706 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201707 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201708 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201709 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201710 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201711 5 7
960210033 NDC-KTN 0 201712 5 7
This should give the result as 7/1 as we have only 1 combination of zeros but result is coming as 1.40